# KeyBy takes a lot of time in Flink Program

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have one Data Stream that reads data from Kafka topic. There is one KeyBy, I calculate different time of two Map functions. Therefore, I understand that KeyBy consumes a lot of time. In fact, when I read one line of Kafka Topic, I have to process it in ten milli second. The code is in following.

```
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, String>> transactionTupleDS =
            getOnlineTransactionsKafka(streamEnv, properties);
    DataStream<CardTransaction> cardTransactionsDS = transactionTupleDS.map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<Long, String>, CardTransaction>() {
        @Override
        public CardTransaction map(Tuple2<Long, String> longStringTuple2) throws Exception {
            return new CardTransaction(System.currentTimeMillis(),longStringTuple2.f1,ctgmap.get(longStringTuple2.f1));
        }
    }).keyBy(new KeySelector<CardTransaction, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer getKey(CardTransaction cardTransaction) throws Exception {
            return cardTransaction.groupID;
        }
    });
    DataStream<ExtractedTransaction> extractedTransactionDS = cardGroupIDsDS.connect(cardTransactionsDS).flatMap(new RichCoFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer, Boolean>, CardTransaction, ExtractedTransaction>() {
        @Override
        public void flatMap1(Tuple2<Integer, Boolean> integerBooleanTuple2, Collector<ExtractedTransaction> collector) throws Exception {

        }

        @Override
        public void flatMap2(CardTransaction cardTransaction, Collector<ExtractedTransaction> collector) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-cardTransaction.ingestionTime);
        }
    });
```

Would you please how I can improve my code to take little time?

Comment: I don't think I understand Your question. Why do You think `keyBy` is the problem here??\

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823420/2000823

Comment: @Dominik Wosinski, because I printed time before and after KeyBy and it was around "200" Milli second.

Comment: @David Anderson, this "https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823420/6640504" solve my problem, many thanks.