# Low latency Flink streaming joins

Tags: java, real-time, apache-flink, flink-streaming, low-latency

I would like to use Flink streaming to process market data with low latency (<1ms).

I have a set of calculations that each subscribe to three streams: slow moving parameter data, a stock price and an FX rate.

e.g.

params (slow ticking: once or twice a day):

```
symbol|asset|strike
12345 |AAPL |1020
12346 |AAPL | 500
12347 |AAPL |1200
12348 |DAX  |2020
12349 |DAX  |2500
12350 |DAX  |2200
12348 |BASF | 400
12349 |BASF | 300
12350 |BA   |1000
```

asset (ticks many times per second):

```
symbol|currency | spot
AAPL | USD | 2300
DAX  | EUR | 4002
BASF | EUR |  304
BA   | GBP |  234
```

fx (ticks many times per second):

```
symbol|rate
USD  | 1
GBP  | 1.2
EUR  | 1.15
NZD  | 1.8
```

Whenever **any** of the stock, FX rate, or parameter data change, then I want to immediately calculate the result and output this as a new stream. This could logically be expressed as a join:

e.g. select price=( params.strike - asset.spot ) * fx.rate from params, asset, fx
where fx.symbol = asset.currency and asset.symbol = params.asset

The stocks and FX rates will be ticking fast (many per second) but at different rates/times, and the parameter data will be ticking very infrequently (once or twice a day). Whenever **ANY** of these values change, I'd like to recalculate and publish the price.

So far I have tried "broadcast" without using windows, which does work, but does mean I need to write quite an amount of custom joining code, and I can't use the more elegant "join" syntax, and definitely not the SQL. It also seems inefficient, since the data is being replicated and broadcast.

In order to use joins I have tried windows, with custom triggering that attempts to send the data as soon as it arrives, and custom eviction code which keeps the latest value. This seems to work but with high latency (many seconds).

Has anyone else any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823420/2000823) for a brain dump on causes of latency in Flink jobs, and things you can do to reduce latency. But getting it below 1ms isn't realistic.

Comment: Thanks David. In fact I have had this working with 1ms latency on a 2015 mac with 100,000 params, 1000 assets. This is using broadcast, with CoProcessFunction, and the optimisations/settings you have mentioned.  Using broadcasting requires plenty of custom code. As soon as I try using windows/joins then this slows down dramatically. This is a shame, since I'd like to use Flink in more of an "SQL-like" way.

Comment: It's interesting to know that you got that to work. What's the parallelism? That seems feasible with parallelism of 1, but I'll be very surprised if it's possible with parallelism > 1. Flink SQL doesn't (yet) have a broadcast join, so the SQL joins all do a keyBy, which hurts performance.

Comment: I might have exaggerated!  I was getting an avg latency 0.1ms, max 7. This was with default parallelism. Setting to 10, the avg goes to 0.4ms with the max latency goes to 40.

Comment: **With all due respect** quantitative statements above about the cadence of FX ToB-Price level changes (+from that derived the expected data-streaming maximum latency limits) are way off the FX-reality. Given the live FIX-Protocol data, one can immediately see many tens of price-impacting changes within a single, **microsecond** time-stamped, FIX-Protocol message. Here, hunting for a **3-orders of magnitude larger latency target (~1 [ms] )**, given the underlying process/data live-changes are **3-orders of magnitude faster (~1 [us] )** does not seem to be a serious engineering practice, is it?

Comment: @user3666197 There are many usages of FX price data: for example a risk management system with complex/expensive pricing models, we can conflate the input rate, and we might target a latency of several seconds, especially where FX is a second order input, and some kinds of market marking of derivatives will find 1ms more than adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Flink SQL can't (yet) do a broadcast join, so the optimisations you were able to implement by hand aren't available with the SQL API. Watch for progress on [FLIP-92](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-92%3A+Add+N-Ary+Stream+Operator+in+Flink), which aims to make this possible.

Comment: Thanks. Look fwd to it. With broadcasting, I have to implement the join myself in a CoProcessFunction. Ideally I could create something like FlatJoinFunction that presents the data after the join.